# Add addtional page parameter before loading the page

Tags: pages, urls, parameter

the problem I got: I need to force a list view for products which are shown on a specific page only for mobile devices, for me the perfect solution would be an additional url parameter -> '&product_view=list', before it is redirected to the page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable

```
$product_view=isset($_GET['product_view']) ? $_GET['product_view'] : 'grid';
```

Now, how to keep it like this with pagination URL's.

```
echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => add_query_arg('product_view', $product_view),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
    'current' => $page,
    'add_args' => array(
        'category' => 'fruit',
        'color' => 'red'
    )
));
```

I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using the [MobileDetect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) class (found in Github, I'm not affiliated) to detect if user is using a mobile device, and then add the url parameter with [`add_query_arg`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) on [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action. Something along these lines.

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php'; // use correct path    
function prefix_add_list_view_param_on_mobile() {
  $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
  $is_product_view = true; // add logic
  // Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
  if ( $is_product_view && $detect->isMobile() && empty( $_GET['product_view'] ) ) {    
    wp_safe_redirect( esc_url( add_query_arg( 'product_view', 'list' ) ) ); // omitting url param results in the current URL being used (the value of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
    exit;
  }  
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'prefix_add_list_view_param_on_mobile' );
```

The code exapmle is untested and might require some tweaking.

Comment: got it!!! appreciate your help!